# Modal view not displaying properly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I am writing an iPad app and want to put an option on the home screen (root view controller) to allow users to e-mail feedback.  I would like the mail to appear with the style "UIModalPresentationFormSheet".  However, when I run the code, it appears full screen. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code I am using:

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSArray *toAddresses = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user@domain.com", nil];
    [picker setToRecipients:toAddresses];
    [toAddresses release];              
    [picker setSubject:@"App Feedback"];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the style of the viewController being presented, not on the one presenting it.. So set the property of the MFMailComposeViewController and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks! I know I was missing something simple!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set modalPresentationStyle on your new view controller, not self.

Comment: Thanks! I know I was missing something simple!